# How to remove a slight gap between the nav bar and first section?

Tags: html, css, scroll, parallax

I have an issue with parallax scrolling with a menu navagation bar. I can't seem to close a gap between the nav bar and first section of my page. Below is the code along with the link to my codepen at the bottom. Thank you in advance. :)

```
<body id="page-top" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-fixed-top">

<!--navagation bar-->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navagation">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-exl-collapse">
            </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top">Hugh Phan</a>
  </div>
  <!--navbar-header-->

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-exl-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li>
        <a class="page-scroll" href="#about">About</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="page-scroll" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!--navbar-collapse-->
</div>
<!--container-->
</nav>
<!-- About Section -->
<section id="about" class="about-section">
<div class="parallax1">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h1>About Hugh Phan</h1>
        <img src="https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/23528932?v=3" style="float: right;" class="smaller-image">
        <p id="aboutme">I'm a Front-End Web Developer with an insatiable appetite for more knowledge when it comes to developing web apps. Knowledgable in: HTML, Javascript, CSS, PHP, MySQL.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</section>
<!--about section-->

<!-- Portfolio Section -->
<section id="portfolio" class="services-section">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h1>My Portfolio</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</section>
<!--portfolio section-->

<!-- Contact Section -->
<section id="contact" class="contact-section">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <h1>Contact Me</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</section>
<!--contact section-->

</body>
```

and here's the css

```
#about {
color: white;
text-shadow: -2px 0 black, 0 1.5px black, 2px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
}

#aboutme {
font-size: 22px;
text-align: left;
padding-top: 40px;
padding-right: 400px;
padding-left: 140px;
}

img {
border-radius: 90%;
}

.smaller-image {
width: 275px;
}

#portfolio {
background-color: #1d2826;
color: white;
}

.parallax1 {
background-image: url("http://desktopgraphy.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/photography-road-dark-city-light-image.jpg");
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
height: 100%;
}
```

and an external link to it all: http://codepen.io/skydreamerjae/pen/pNPbXa

Comment: do you have a external link for `scrolling.css` because the `padding-top:150px;` located at scrolling.css and this causes the gap on the top.

Comment: aaah thank you! youre absolutely right

Comment: Glad that i helped.